# Prove that if $R$ is a PID then every fractional ideal of $R$ is principal fractional ideal?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

If $R$ is a principal ideal domain then every fractional ideal of $R$ is principal fractional ideal. How to prove this? Please give some hints.

Thanks

Comment: Let's look at a simple example. Suppose $R = \mathbb Z$ and suppose $I \subset \mathbb Q$ is a fractional ideal such that $3I$ is a (genuine) ideal in $\mathbb Z$. Then $3I$ is principal. For example, $3I$ could be $ (2)\subset \mathbb Z$ (say). But then, $I$ would be the principal fractional ideal $(\frac 2 3)$. Can you see how this generalises?

Comment: @KennyWong Thank you very much, I got it.

Comment: I think this is a theorem in most introductory algebraic number theory texts. I don't have a single one of them at the moment, so I can't give you any page numbers.